# Binding Datagrid with observable collection wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have an Datagrid with multiple column this has itemsource={Binding} and in code behind I have set DataContext to an ObservableCollection

my customClass has properties like title,type,language, type1(CustomClass),type2(CustomClass)

now my problem is that in one column type I have text value say 'A' or 'B' now if the value is A then the object of my customClass will have an object of type1 and type2 is set to null and if type has value 'B' then type1 is set to null and type2 has values.

now in language I want to bind in such a way if type has A then take value of type1.someProperty if it has B then take value of type2.someProperty.

here is what I have in my xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_Content" Margin="0,60,-0.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="505" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding _title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgType" Header="Content Type" Binding="{Binding  _type}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=dgType, Path=Content}" Value="A" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding type1.someProperty}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style></DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created At" Binding="{Binding _createdAt}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit/View">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Edit/View" Click="View_Click"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: @Blam i tried multivalue converter as well but my observable collection is in the mainwindows and when i implement IMultivalueConvertor to my customClass i dont know how can i fetch the value of the type to check further....

Comment: @Blam in my customClass i have a property named 'type'(string) ,'type1'(custom class) and 'type2'(custom class) which can have value either 'A' or 'B', if it is A then I initialize type1 with some values and type2 = null and vice and versa.

Comment: @Blam i will explain again, i have a wpf app with mainWindow and three class say 'customClass', 'Type1Class' and 'Type2Class'. customClass has properties like title(string),type(string),language(string),type1(Type1Class) and type2(Type2Class). In mainWindows i bind dataContext of DataGrid to an observableCollection<customClass> and values are populated. Now based on the value of customClass.type, the properties type1 or type2 is initialized at a time only one object has values other is null(if type is 'A' then type1 object initialized and type2 remains null)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68496/discussion-between-goldsmit409-and-blam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it if any one needs it.

Xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgContent" Margin="0,60,-0.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="505" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Content Type" Binding="{Binding  Type}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Content}">
                    <Binding Path="{x:Static local:MainWindow.cl}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created At" Binding="{Binding CreatedAt}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit/View">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Edit/View" Click="View_Click"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        if (((Content)values[0]).Type == "movie")
        {
            return ((Content)values[0]).Movie.Language;
        }
        else
            return ((Content)values[0]).Video.Language;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { return "EXception"; }
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
       object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
}
```